# How to check approximate App store size of app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, size

I used to do it but I haven't done it in a while and i've added to my game. Don't remember where on Xcode I can check the approximate app store size of my app.

I plugged in the iPhone into my mac. I clicked on Windows, Devices expecting it to be there but it wasn't. I don't remember.

Where on Xcode can I check the approximate app store size of my app?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The Organizer has this functionality for Archives. So, you'll need to create an archive:

1. Product > Archive (you need the iOS device scheme selected here, which means you need a valid signing identity set up)
2. Window > Organizer
3. Select the "Archives" tab.
4. Select your archive, and in the header detail view, click "Estimate Size"

Comment: You mean Product > Archive.  Not Build >Archive. But thanks I got it now.

Comment: You're totally right. Thanks for the fact-check. Fixed in the original answer!

Comment: Like the answer below says, newer versions of Xcode 6 don't have this functionality baked in. Instead, you can right-click (control-click) on your archive in the Organizer, and click "Show in Finder..." -- from there you can "Get Info..." on the file and see its size. This may not be exact -- I am not sure if there is compression that takes place between the archive and IPA stages.

Comment: Update 2017: Checking the file size of the archive in the Finder doesn't tell you what's the size of the file that user will download from the App Store. Here is how to find that out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42317342/517865

Comment: This answer should no longer be the accepted answer since it is no longer valid for a long time.

Comment: No longer a valid answer.  Down voting

Comment: No longer valid

Answer (score 53):

To find out what's the size of the file that user will download from the App Store, you need to do the following.

1. Archive your app
2. Export your archive for testing outside the store.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Select “Export for specific devices” and choose “All compatible device variants” from the pop-up menu.
   [image]
4. Select "Rebuild from bitcode." *EDIT: this step doesn't exist since as late as Xcode 9.4.1.*
5. In the output folder, you will find `App Thinning Size Report.txt`, which breaks down the compressed and uncompressed file sizes, plus the size of any On Demand Resources, for each device type.

For more information take a look at [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html).

Comment: This works in Xcode 9.4.1. The only difference is that step 4 no longer exists. When you click Next in step 3 it builds the ipa files and the report text file.

Comment: Thanks for the update @PamelaCook-LightBeCorp ! I will edit the answer.

Comment: This was great. Thought I selected 'Save for Development Deployment' instead. And just used my dev cert + profiles to create the ipa. https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva1f2ab5a2

Comment: In Xcode 15, there's no "Export" button. Choose "Distribute", then choose "Release Testing" for Ad Hoc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The organizer in xcode no longer shows this info for some reason. However if you archive your project and in the organizer right click on the file you archived and click "show in finder" and you will be able to see the size when you right click and choose "get info".

Comment: The file you find here has nothing to do with the app size on the app store. It contains lots of things like dsym files and unoptimized and non stripped assets

Answer (score -1):

I can't see the "Estimate Size" in Xcode (Version 7.0.1).

Following with josefdlange , I can find the "Show in Finder..." when I Click the header detail view(small icon) .

[image]

Comment: The file you find here has nothing to do with the app size on the app store. It contains lots of things like dsym files and unoptimized and non stripped assets.