# how to reduce my app size for new and existing apps?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am a beginner when it comes to developing for iOS and I have two questions regarding the size of my app.

1. I have created an iOS application using a storyboard along with the code and its size is 25MB. How can I reduce the size of my application?
2. If I where start a new project, and use code rather than a storyboard, would this reduce the application size?

Comment: this question is very confuse. Please rewrite it clearer.

Comment: Are third-party libraries taking up too much space？

Comment: no i am not using any third party

Comment: its like a table view to store data in my table view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the size of an app is determined with it's resources size (images, files, sounds/music, etc). 
By reducing the size of your images, reusing them when it is possible, and using the optimal resolution, you should be able to reduce the app size, and the same applies with sound.

Storyboards are an XML file, and text does not use a lot of memory.

Comment: i am not using any image ,sound, even i am not using launch imges too...i have one table view to store data thats it.  @aramusss

Comment: How do you calculate the size of the app?

Comment: sory i am new to ios. when i run my simulator .i have seen my memory size is 25. mb....

Comment: Use this solution to check the real app size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152093/how-to-check-approximate-app-store-size-of-app-in-xcode

Comment: If that is the solution of the answer, please mark it as the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce App Size, you will have to reduce the size of images and the sound files you are using. There are various tools available which can compress your PNGs, without losing content in them. Similarly, you can also reduce their size from Photoshop as well. Lesser the size of your PNGs, lesser will be the size of your app.

Making app in Storyboard or making it through code will not effect your App's size. Any app size lesser than 100mb is good, as it can be downloaded through 3G as well. Above that will have to be downloaded through Wifi only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any kind of resources mention above , than u must be  storing data in your phone memory either using NSUserDefault etc that you are showing in your tableView try to remove data from phonememory and store it in your server memory.
Storyboard is the best and the easiest way to develop application.