# How to remove extra linked images in ios .app bundle

Tags: ios, assets, xcode9

When I checked my app size its going approx 120MB right now. Out of which mostly was taken my extra resources. Later on I removed all extras and added compressed version of launch images also 2 extra pods. All this reduced my app size my 30 MB. But still When I checked my .app package contents its showing some extra LaunchImages which I may have added earlier and are still somehow connected to my code. I am unable to find out their source. Please help me how to remove these extra linked images from my code.

Comment: Did you check all .xcassets files and bundle resources?

Comment: please find in assets.xcassets and remove

Comment: I did check my assets.xcassets file but I am not able to file these files there.    Earlier somehow there were 2 assets in my project and later I deleted the unwanted one. I am thinking somehow those files are still linked to my project. But I don't know how to search and remove them.

Comment: How did you determine the app size? Did you use the **Estimate Size** option of the Organizer after archiving it? ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152093/how-to-check-approximate-app-store-size-of-app-in-xcode )
Otherwise you might be looking at the extracted size of your app that is typically bigger.

Comment: I build the code and check the size of .app file. After I clicked "Show Package Content" there I am seeing these extra images.

Comment: @Arti May be you delete the reference of file..please search in app bundle with file name

Comment: @Arti Try to select **Product -> Clean**, delete **Derived Data** (described in answer below) and **remove the App** from the device by long pressing and deleting it. Then check if the image reappears when you build again. Xcode works in strange ways sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Delete unwanted file from bundle resources

- Go to your Project settings
- Select your application target under **Targets**
- Select the **Build Phases** Tab
- Expand the step **Copy Bundle Resources**
- Remove and unwanted Files that shall not be copied into your bundle

[image: Steps to show bundle resources]

#### Delete unwanted file from Assets.xcassets

Also, check if your project contains an `Assets.xcassets` assets library and look if you find your unwanted image within.

[image: Steps to find unwanted image in Assets.xcassets]

#### Sanity check

When sometimes everything you try fails and Xcode behaves strangely, make sure your problem is not already fixend and only caused by cached resources.

As sanity check you can

- Clean Build (**Product -> Clean)**
- Delete Derived Data (Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder in Finder or via Terminal command `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`)
- Remove App from Device by long-pressing and deleting.
  Afterwards build your app again and check if the problem persists.

Comment: I am not able to find these files there.

Comment: Are there multiple Asstets.xcassets referenced under these bundle ressources? (The old old one that you did delete)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the items from Assets catalog if it is an image.
Remove unwanted files from respective directories.
Remove the Derive Data.
Clean the project. Then archive.

How to remove Derive Data:
Xcode-> Prefrences-> Locations-> Derive Data.

Remove content of Derive Data folder.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 has got a new feature called App thinning. Xcode and Appstore handles downloading of images that are relevant to specific iPhones thereby reducing the size of the app. You can just enable App thinning while moving your App to the Appstore. This is one of the method to reduce your app size.

you can check this [App thinning](https://www.appcoda.com/app-thinning/)